# MYSQL Function/Procedures

Tags: mysql, database, function, stored-procedures

I have to write function that return total number of records from table where Table name will be input.

```
drop function if exists totalRecord;

delimiter //
create function totalRecord(tname varachar(20))
      returns int
     begin
        declare result int;
        select count(*) into result from tname;
        return result;
    end;
//
delimiter ;
```

After Running Program Output is empty result set but table contains records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL here because SQL doesn't know the table name you are passing and functions doesn't allow dynamic sql in Mysql. So you probably need below -

```
drop procedure if exists totalRecord;

delimiter //
create procedure totalRecord(tname varchar(20))
     begin
        declare result int;
        declare v_Sql VARCHAR(2000);
        SET v_Tab_Name=tname;
        SET v_Sql = concat(' Select count(1) from ' , v_Tab_Name);
        PREPARE stmt FROM v_Sql;
        EXECUTE stmt ;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    end;
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: And where is RETURN?

Comment: @Akina, Functions having dynamic SQL are not allowed in Mysql.

Comment: @HarshJoshi, You forgot to accept the answer though. BTW, you're welcome.